# python 3 Value adding elements from a list and printing the total

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, printing, element

I have hit rough spot in trying to figure out a problem that I am having with my code. 
I would like the output to result in:

```
Enter the high integer for the range 100
Enter the low integer for the range 20
Enter the integer for the multiples 15
List was created
The list has 5 elements.
90 75 60 45 30 
Average of multiples is 60.00
```

I can figure out the "The list was created" part ....but the where it says "The list has 5 elements." on my code it keeps returning 30 instead 5. I was wondering if someone may point me into the right direction or portion to return the correct value. I greatly appreciate your help in this matter.

```
def main():
    x = int(input('Enter the high integer for the range: '))
    y = int(input('Enter the low integer for the range: '))
    z = int(input('Enter the integer for the multiples: '))
    mylist = show_multiples(x,y,z)
    show_multiples(x,y,z)
    show_list(mylist)

def show_multiples(x,y,z):
    mylist = []
    for num in range(x,y,-1):
        if num % z == 0:  
            mylist.append(num)
    return mylist
    print ('List was created')

def show_list(mylist): 

    total = 0  
    for value in mylist:  
        total += value 
        average = total / len(mylist)
    print ('The list has', value, 'elements.')
    print (mylist,end=' ')
    print ()
    print ('Average of multiples is', format(average, '.2f'))

main()
```

Comment: Why do you call `show_multiples` twice?

Comment: Also, `print ('List was created')` should probably go _before_ the return statement if you ever want to actually execute that line :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just printing the wrong value:

```
print ('The list has', value, 'elements.')
```

should be:

```
print ('The list has', len(mylist), 'elements.')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will re-read the section on the len portions. I did put the "List" inside of the return but it is printing twice now?

Comment: @WillyJoe -- That's because you're calling `show_multiples` twice. :-)